# Unable to restore Windows Update Service (wuauserv) despite Admin and LocalSystem privileges

Tags: windows, permissions, windows-update, administrator, psexec

One of my school's Windows 11 computers kept failing to update. When I go to the Updates tab on Settings and press Check Updates, it always displays the `One of the update services is not running properly, but you can try to run a troubleshooter to fix the problem`. I have tried the following options:

1. Built-in Troubleshooter

It was unable to detect any issues.

2. `services.msc` (Administrator)

Here I noticed that **Windows Update was disabled**. When I tried to set it to Auto or Manual, I got `Access Denied`.

3. `regedit` (Administrator)

I located `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\wuauserv`. There I tried to change the value of the `Start` key to 2 or 3 but I was once again blocked. Even when I hit confirm without modifying the value I got the same `Permission denied` message.

4. `cmd` (Administrator)

```
C:\Windows\system32> sc config wuauserv start=demand
[SC] ChangeServiceConfig Failure 5:

Access Denied.
```

5. `PsExec`
   I tried methods 3 and 4 using the PsExec(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec) tool to run it as `LocalSystem`. However I still somehow lacked the permissions.

I explained the need to do a fresh install to the higher-ups but they were not convinced at all. Is there any way to enable Windows Update without it?

Comment: If it were my own PC, I'd download the ISO and reinstall... but it's *the schools*.  Either return it to IT to fix, or remove any sensitive data, since I would not consider it trustworthy, and use it only as required.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik - my read on this is the OP **is** the school's IT. I'd be inclined to nuke & pave it, though, too.

Comment: If you *are* IT staff, then you have at least two people on this site supporting your need to clean that computer and reinstall Windows, either keeping files, or *de novo*. It takes little time, and should not be an issue for which an administrator should be consulted. [I might ask the admin to *show* how to fix it without reinstallation, but then, my job is not at stake ;-) ]